# How does hash(row id + year) partition work?

Tags: mysql, database, database-partitioning

I'm new to this with partitions. Didn't knew it existed but came aware when I tried to make our new `'url_hash'` column unique in a table in our database. And got the error message:

> A UNIQUE INDEX must include all columns in the table's partitioning function

This is a database created by another person that I don't know and who are not involved in the project anymore.

I have tried to read mysql documentation and read on forums about Partition. What it is and how it works. Understand the purpose, to "divide" a table in to several "parts" so it becomes faster to retrieve relevant data. A common example is to partition in to years intervals. But most examples shows an manual method. Where you decide for example less than three specific years. For example:

```
PARTITION BY RANGE ( YEAR(separated) ) (
    PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (1991),
    PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (1996),
    PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (2001),
    PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE
);
```

But in our table, the partitions are created this way:

```
PARTITION BY HASH ( `feeditemsID` + YEAR(`feeddate`))
PARTITIONS 3;
```

What does that mean? How does our partition work?

`feeditemsID` is the unique ID for every row in our table.

Comment: Is your question about how hash partitioning works, or about how to fix the error you get?

Comment: Well, both. I thought by getting to understand how this kind of partitioning work, I might be able to avoid error. I like to know why a solution works.

Answer (score 2):

When you use hash partitioning, the partition that contains each record is determined by calculating a hash code from the expression `feaditemsID + YEAR(feeddate)`, and then finding the modulus of this code by the number of partitions. So if the hash code for a row is 123, it calculates `123 % 3`, which is `0`, so the record goes into partition `0`.

This is explained inthe [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-hash.html).

As stated there,

> **Note**
>   If a table to be partitioned has a UNIQUE key, then any columns supplied as arguments to the HASH user function or to the KEY's ***column_list*** must be part of that key.

In your case, the table's primary key needs to be:

```
PRIMARY KEY (feeditemsID, feeddate)
```

Assuming `feeditemsID` is already unique (presumably it's an auto-increment column), adding `feeddate` to the primary is redundant as far as keeping the data unique is concerned, but it's needed to satisfy the partitioning requirement. Putting `feeditemsID` first in the composite key will allow it to be used by itself to optimize table lookup.

This requirement is probably because each partition has its own index. When inserting/updating a row and checking for uniqueness, it only checks the index of the partition where that row will be stored. So when it finds the partition using the hash function, it needs to be sure that this partition will uniquely contain the indexed columns.

For more information see

[Partitioning Keys, Primary Keys, and Unique Keys](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-limitations-partitioning-keys-unique-keys.html)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Why `feeddate` could be needed in the unique key? However, is it assumed that the partitionated tables are sorted by feeditemsID ASC? I guess it should be, how else would it know how to calculate to know which partition to search in? How should I do to make my column `url_hash` to be unique? Delete all this partitions and create new ones with unique keys built on a hash containing this column? Or what?

Comment: Read the quoted documentation: All columns referenced in the `HASH` function have to be in the unique key.

Comment: It knows which partition to search in by calculating the hash of `feeditemsID + feeddate`.

Comment: I think the reason for this requirement is that each partition has its own index, and it can only guarantee uniqueness within a partition. You can't have a unique index on some other column, because the duplicates might end up in different partitions, and it can't detect that duplication.

Comment: `All columns referenced in the HASH function have to be in the unique key`.  Okay, don't understand why feeddate has to be in the unique key. Do you have a clue why you think it's needed? The problem now is that I initially is trying to make it impossible to insert rows with same url than another. Thats why I try to create a unique url_hash column. But I now realized that if so, no other columns can be in that key. How should I do? To keep partitions but make the unique key just containing the `url_hash` column?

Comment: The hash function uses `YEAR(feeddate)`, so `feeddate` has to be in the unique key.

Comment: You can't prevent duplicate `url_hash`, because it uses `feeditemsID` and `feeddate` to find the partition. Then it looks for a duplicate `url_hash` only in that partition's index. If there's a duplicate in one of the other partitions, it won't find it.

Comment: Okay, but if I replace `feeditemsID` with `url_hash`? Then it's at least impossible to insert same url + year? Or no...The year has nothing to do with what partition to search in? Same year can exist in different partition tables, right? So, any suggestion on how I should do?

Comment: Maybe you could use `primary key (feeditemsID), unique key (url_hash), partition by hash(CONCAT(feeditemsID, url_hash))`.

Comment: A stupid question but; How do I delete partitions without losing any data?

Comment: `1564 - This partition function is not allowed` when I'm trying `ALTER TABLE feeditems PARTITION BY HASH(CONCAT(feeditemsID, url_hash)) PARTITIONS 4;`

Comment: Looks like there are restrictions on the functions that can be used in the partition hash: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-limitations-functions.html

Comment: I succeeded to partition with `LINEAR KEY(url_hash )` with no errors. But is this a good partition?

Comment: I have no idea. Everything I know about partitioning I learned from the documentation in the past 6 hours.